# Make landscape the only autorotate orientation for all view controllers at once

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, device-orientation

I know that I have to add this

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight);
}
```

to a view controller in order to make that specific screen lock in landscape mode, but do I have to do this for every view controller? Is there a way to just do a master lock that would apply to all view controllers?

Comment: If you have a main view controller that wraps a bunch of sub-views/view controllers, then you should be able to do it once there and it will effect all of the sub-views.

Comment: I actually do not have that, although i wish that I did, I am just pushing viewControllers through a navController :/

Comment: UINavigationController extends UIViewController, so, you should extend UINavigationController and implement `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` as Abhi suggests.  Then use that class for your navController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create you own subclass of `UIViewController`, which implements `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`.

Then any subclass of that will inherit the behaviour.

Comment: Perhaps you meant UIViewController?

Comment: Why is it that I have the device supported orientations set to the two landscape modes, but it is still allowed to run in portrait view?

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to lock the orientation for the entire app, maybe there's a single view inside it (eg: taking a photo, or an embedded web browser) where you do want the user to be able to auto-rotate. Therefore orientation locking is generally specific to a single view.

Comment: well its a game, and the graphics really don't work in portrait mode

Comment: i just dont get why `- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
 return YES;
}` doesnt read that the only two supported orientations that I have are both landscapes and not portraits

Comment: It depends where and how you set the orientation. The view structure of an iOS app can be complicated, if it's not working how you expect then perhaps you're doing something wrong? That's not something we can really discuss in comments - you'd have to ask another separate question providing more details.

Answer (score 0):

Since you mentioned it's a game, then I agree it is a good idea to really make this apply to the entire app.

If you click on your project in the project navigator, then select your target, and in the Summary tab all four orientations are listed and you can enable just the ones you want.

For non-game apps I wouldn't advice this, since there might be one view somewhere which needs another orientation.

Comment: Thats just the thing, I only have landscape left and landscape right selected there, as do i have in my .plist under supported orientations  but it still adjusts when I flip it to portrait... thoughts?

Comment: Then perhaps you do need to do both, I'm not sure.